# Why is "-" (dash) giving "Unexpected token error" on Babelify with Gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gulp, babeljs

I am setting up (or actually modifying existing) project with Browserify and Babelify. For some reason I can't configure my gulpfile properly. The project itself is a React project, if it matters.

I got rid of most of the problems, but now I am getting "Unexpected token" error on Browserify. It is caused by React components or html elements with attribute names which have a dash, ie. the following:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse">
```

My Browserify task:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {

  browserify('./src/js/main.js')
    .transform(babelify.configure({

      presets: ["react", "es2015"]
    }))
    .bundle()
    .on('error', function(err){
      process.stdout.write('' + err + '\n');
      notifier.notify({

        title: 'Error',
        message: err,
        sound: true,
        wait: true
        }, function (err, response) {
      });
    })
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "srcd-mockup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.12",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.5",
    "browserify": "^11.2.0",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "node-notifier": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^0.14.1",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.1",
    "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-component": "^0.27.2",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^2.0.4",
    "updeep": "^0.10.1",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.12",
    "babelify": "^7.0.2",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**What I tried before:**

The weird thing here is that previously I had similar project with similar dependencies and config, and it worked fine.

Then I tried to set up the new one, and first I got Unexpected token error on this line on my main.js (initial render of React):

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

The error was caused by "(". Then there was no presets on Babelify.

If I only have "react" on presets, I get "ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'", because of, well importing.

**Questions:**

- Is this related to Babelify or can it be caused by other module or dependency?
- Is this related to Babel 6?
- Why is dash causing the error?
- How should I set this up?

Comment: *"Is this related to Babel 6?"* Potentially. What happens if you use Babel 5?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug as of Babel version 6.0.12 which is rendering `data-*` tags as object keys without quoting them, resulting in invalid JS syntax.

You can use a pre-v6 version of Babel, or else wait for someone to submit a fix.

UPDATE:

A fix for this just got checked into the repo, so this will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Actually I got it working by installing Babelify 6.4.0.